# how to pass different variables in Controller, in different states

Tags: angularjs

Using `resolve` property in `$stateProvider`

I am new to angularjs and trying to use the stateProvider like

```
$stateProvider
            // Category routes
            .state('category', {

                url: '/category',
                templateUrl:'public/templates/category/category.html',
            })
            .state('category.list', {
                url: '/list',
                templateUrl:'public/templates/category/category.list.html',
                resolve: {
                    // A String value resolves to a service.
                    categoriesResource: 'categoriesResource',

                    categories: function(categoriesResource) {
                        return categoriesResource.query();
                    }

                },
                controller: 'CategoryCtrl',
            })
            .state('category.new', {
                url: '/new',
                templateUrl: 'public/templates/category/category.new.html',
                resolve: {
                    categories: function() {
                        return {}
                    }
                },
                controller: 'CategoryCtrl',
            })

            .state('category.update', {
                   url:'/{id:[0-9]{1,4}}',
                   templateUrl: 'public/templates/category/category.update.html',
                   resolve: {
                        categoriesResource: 'categoriesResource',
                        categories: function(categoriesResource) {
                        return categoriesResource.query({id:$stateParams.id});
            }
              },
              controller: 'CategoryCtrl',

      })
```

and in Category controller I am passing arguments like

```
.controller('CategoryCtrl',  ['$scope', '$state', 'categories', '$location', function($scope, $state, categories, $location) {
        $scope.categories = categories;

}])
```

now my problem in the `categories` will be `resolved` only when I call the `list` state
for `new` and `update` I don't need `categories` and in case of `update` I want to pass on `category` in `CategoryCtrl`

what will be the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

--> First define the controller

```
function ContactController($scope) {

//...

}
```

-->  Let us check the syntax to create a module and add controller to it:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];

$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.contacts.push($scope.contact);
    $scope.contact = "";
}
}]);
```

In above example we created a module called myApp using angular.module() method. Then we added a controller ContactController to this module. This is just an alternate way of defining a controller but recommended one.

Answer (score 0):

You should define two different controllers. First controller should be CategoryListController which is used in the `list` scenario. This can then take the `categories` through `resolve`.

The second controller should be CategoryEditController, which would do create(new) and update. This can take the category that needs to be updated using the `resolve`.